# Export Grid.Mvc to Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

---------------- view page-----

```
  <div class="scroll" id="activity">
    @Html.Grid(Model).Named("x").Columns(columns => {
    }
  </div>
```

---------java script---------

```
  $("#excelbtn").click(function (e) {
    window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#activity').html()));
    e.preventDefault();

  });
```

but it exports only one page of data.

I want all data to export at once.

Comment: have you find the answer, I have to do same thing.

Comment: no till now i have n't get any answer sorry.